# Can't access AWS Web Console for Couchbase

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, couchbase

I followed the guide to setup the Couchbase Server and Couchbase Sync Gateway [found here](http://blog.couchbase.com/2015/november/database-on-amazon-installing-couchbase-ami-on-aws).

Upon starting up the instance, I am able to access the Web Console for a few minutes before I can't get anything to load and it all times out; upon this event, if I refresh the page, I am completely unable to get back to the web console.

I'm pretty sure the security groups are correct, as they were setup by default when I chose this software for the EC2.

Currently, my instance is using an m3.medium tier. I already tried switching to an m3.large, but that didn't work any better.

I appreciate any and all help.

Comment: To help diagnose, you can run [cbcollect_info][1] tool to collect logs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm relaying this from one of the Couchbase PM's:

Since this AMI is pretty old I would recommend below approach for mitigating this issue -

1. Start Couchbase Server Community/Enterprise Edition AMI
2. Install Couchbase Sync Gateway on Couchbase Server instance (you can find the [complete documentation for that here](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/develop/guides/sync-gateway/running-sync-gateway/connecting-sync-gateway-to-couchbase-server/index.html).

I would also encourage you to post this on the Couchbase Forums, or you can open an issue at [issues.couchbase.com](https://issues.couchbase.com/)